# how to put encryption in place while creating db link between on premise db 12c and cloud db 11g

Tags: oracle, encryption, cloud

we need to create db link between our db on premise and our medical db on oracle cloud. Our main concern is the data encryption while data transfer happen. Need a solution.

Comment: Is the cloud database an Autonomous ATP or ADW instance, or is it installed on your own VM?

Answer (score 0):

[Configuring Network Data Encryption and Integrity for Oracle Servers and Clients](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asoconfg.htm#ASOAG020)

[Configuring Encryption on the Client and the Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asoconfg.htm#i1006542)

> The `sqlnet.ora` file on the two systems should contain the following entries:
>
> - On the server:
>
>   `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = [accepted | rejected | requested |
>     required]
>     SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER = (valid_encryption_algorithm [,valid_encryption_algorithm])`
> - On the client:
>
>   `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = [accepted | rejected | requested | required]
>     SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (valid_encryption_algorithm [,valid_encryption_algorithm])`

[SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#CHDIJDJJ)

[SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF208)

Or SSL:

[Configuring Secure Sockets Layer Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asossl.htm#ASOAG070)

Note that SSL is not just there for authentication, but for encryption purpose as well.